# Python learning

Tags: scripting

I started to learn python for Blender and wish to follow a path so I can master it (... and of course constantly keep learning).

My end goal is character animation. In particular I wish to use python scripting for the following:

rigging
Facial motion capture
Body motion capture
Lip sync from sound
Automating curves in the graph editor (bounciness).
Wiggle armature

I know there are good and/or partial solutions for these items. I aim to understand what I use so I can adapt it to my needs.

In other words, I need to learn coding (no previous experience), have a decent understand of python and than apply it on Blender with orientation to the above mentioned items.

I intend to invest time and learn it seriously.

My question is how to? I'm looking for a comprehensive source that could help me pass the Rubicon. That is books and/or online course that are geared towards character animation scripting.

As I intend to invest time to learn it seriously I wish to follow a learning path, a resource that I can trust would allow me to cross the Rubicon.

I started to learn from Blender documentation, youtube tutorial for blender, Mosh tutorial for python.. This will always be a valuable resource but I feel I need a more structured path to ensure that I don't run allover the place.
Any tips, references? advice?... would be highly appreciated.

PS -In case you find my question isn't specific enough, or too subjective, for this forum, can you kindly inform where I can ask this type of question?

Comment: This tutorial seems rather in-depth and nicely focused - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqX5wh4YeRw

Comment: thanks for the reference, I watched it already. It is a good one (those Curtis made b4 and after also).  I want to develop the know-how as to how write like this one day.